# Unable to call this method from other method

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude

This is my method calling for GPS coordinate. It works just fine using button onclick from GUI. But whenever I try to call it from other method it crash my apps.

```
public void getPattern(View v){
    String s = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=05.445560,100.424200&ie=UTF8&z=16&iwIoc=addr&om=1speed:000.0&imei=355689019472548";
   // String s = messageBox.getText().toString();
  //  Log.d("check", s);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    int i =0;
    Float n[] = new Float[4];
        while (m.find()) {
               System.out.println(m.group());
               n[i]= Float.parseFloat(m.group());
               i++;
            }

            LatLng locLatLng = new LatLng(n[0],n[1]);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(locLatLng).zoom(15).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(locLatLng).title("Here's your car dude!!!").snippet("Found it!!");
            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            googleMap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();

}
```

The error so far starting from LatLng onwards. If I removed this code and of course the (View v) and call from main method such as `getPattern();` It work just fine but I need th rest of LatLng code so that It can automatically get the position from the extracted Lat long of string s. The n variable captured the lat long data correctly.

I mean I want to call this method from code such as within the onCreate or somewhere else without interacting with button or any GUI element. for example I have this method

```
public static void updateMessageBox(String msg) { 
    messageBox.setText(msg); 
    getPattern(); 
}
```

This caused my app to crash. If I remove the `LatLng` code onwards it work just fine and also remove the `(View v)`

Comment: show the function in which you tried to call this function

Comment: updatemessagebox method calling the getPattern method..I found the error but unable to solved it..the culprit is String s that I'm using. I cannot use any variable input from GUI. I can only use static variable define in the method.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call the button **onClick** function put the content in the new `method` and then call the function inside the **onClick** function.

```
public void getPattern(View v){

    getPatternmatch();
    }



    public void getPatternmatch(){
        String s = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=05.445560,100.424200&ie=UTF8&z=16&iwIoc=addr&om=1speed:000.0&imei=355689019472548";
       // String s = messageBox.getText().toString();
      //  Log.d("check", s);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        int i =0;
        Float n[] = new Float[4];
            while (m.find()) {
                   System.out.println(m.group());
                   n[i]= Float.parseFloat(m.group());
                   i++;
                }

                LatLng locLatLng = new LatLng(n[0],n[1]);
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(locLatLng).zoom(15).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(locLatLng).title("Here's your car dude!!!").snippet("Found it!!");
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                googleMap.addMarker(marker).showInfoWindow();

    }
```

Comment: you cannot call the button onClick method directly... put the content in the onClick method to the other method and call that function instead of onClick method